# Connecting to Hive using Spark-SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am running hive queries using Spark-SQL.
I made a hive context object

```
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc);
```

Then when I am trying to run the command:

```
hiveContext.sql("use db_name");
```

OR

```
hiveContext.hiveql("use db_name");
```

It doesnt work. It says `database not found.`
When I try to run

```
val db = hiveContext.hiveql("show databases");
db.collect.foreach(println);
```

It prints nothing. Just prints `[default]`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you configured the right `metsastore` in `hive-default.xml`? and copied the same file in `SPARK_HOME/conf` folder?

Comment: I am working in cloudera distribution. Do I still need to take care of that?

Comment: On which platform are you submitting your Spark jobs? Standalone/ Yarn or Mesos or ?

Comment: I am submitting jobs on yarn.

Comment: Than you have to check the Hive Configurations of Yarn and not CDH. Check if the mentioned Hive Database does exists and the same hive config is used by your Spark Jobs.

Comment: I am connecting to spark-shell and executing statements from shell environment and not doing spark-submit

Comment: Would suggest to add compelete details (env, configurations etc)  in the question itself. Will be easy to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM database.table")
```